# Append more dollar sign ($) with variable in powershell

Tags: powershell, msbuild

```
 PowerShell.ps1

 $ScriptDir = Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

 &  $ScriptDir\Test\bin\debug\Test.exe  /createpackage$$$ScriptDir$$$ScriptDir

 Test.exe
            var cpc = args.FirstOrDefault(a => a.StartsWith("/CREATEPACKAGE", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
            if (cpc != null)
            {
                var options = cpc.Split(new string[] { "$$" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                if (options.Length < 3)
                {
                    _Logger.Error("Missing required <path> and <output dir> parameters.");
                    PrintUsage();
                    Environment.Exit((int)ExitCode.Failure);
                }
```

test.exe is accepting 3 arguments using split with $$ dollar sign.
But not able to add $$ with $scriptdir in powershell command line argumnet.

```
Like below I  Needed in powershell commandline. How can i add $$? 
/createpackagePackage$$C:\WorkSpace\DEV$$C:\WorkSpace\DEV
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `-f` (string format) operator; e.g.:

```
& $ScriptDir\Test\bin\debug\Test.exe ('/createpackage$${0}$${1}' -f $ScriptDir,$ScriptDir)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the escape character ` on the $

```
 &  "$ScriptDir\Test\bin\debug\Test.exe  /createpackage`$`$`$ScriptDir`$`$`$ScriptDir"
```

You could also probably leverage the stop processing command `--%`

```
 &  $ScriptDir\Test\bin\debug\Test.exe --%  /createpackage$$$ScriptDir$$$ScriptDir
```